# Which not displaying location of executible actually run

Tags: linux, path, suse

I have a version of SVN on my system in /usr/bin/svn. This is too old to use with some repositories so I compiled a newer version in /home/user/built/bin/svn which works fine. I added this to my PATH so it should be run first.

Typing

```
which svn
```

produces

```
/home/user/built/bin/svn
```

however typing

```
svn --version
```

reveals that it us using the old version still. if I run

```
/home/user/built/bin/svn --version
```

then the correct version is displayed.

Since the custom version is first in my $PATH, and which lists it first why is the older version being invoked when I run svn? I thought which used your $PATH to find executables in the same fashion as the shell?

Comment: whereis svn
svn: /usr/bin/svn /usr/bin/X11/svn /usr/share/man/man1/svn.1.gz

Whereis doesn't list the custom version on the PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
type svn
```

to figure out (a) what it is, (b) where it is or what its definition is. Also check that PATH really contains what you think it does

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I hadn't come across hash before. One of those things you can normally take for granted and then bites you if you don't know what is going on under the hood! :)

Comment: Oh yeah hash. The next evil thing after ldconfig and even more hideous.

Answer (score 1):

Type gives:

```
type svn
svn is hashed (/usr/bin/svn)
```

Running

```
hash -r
```

has now fixed the problem!

Credit to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You sure you don't have a symbolic link to svn somewhere else in your path?

Comment: I don't think so, typing:

which svn -a

only gives the two paths. Would a symbolic link show up there?
/home/user/built/bin/svn
/usr/bin/svn